# 500 internal server error in rails with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a text box that displays a list of sorted users that sorts per every typed letter. From there the person can add the user as a collaborator. The result should be kind of like facebook's search feature when you are searching to add new friends. When I press a key I see a new 500 internal server error in the network section of the browsers console. Here is a snippet of the response:

```
 <h1>
    NoMethodError
      in CollaborationsController#collaboration_search
  </h1>
</header>

<div id="container">
  <h2>undefined method `[]&#39; for nil:NilClass</h2>
```

So I think the ajax is getting fired to the server but there is something wrong with the controller. Here is my code for the view, views/collaborations/_new.html.erb:

```
    <%= form_for [wiki, collaboration] do |f|%>

<div class = "col-md-8">

    <div class = "form-group">
      <%= f.label :user_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :user_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter name"  %>

    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
      <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= @users_by_name.to_a %>
</div>

  </div>

</div>
<%end%>
```

where the form above is a partial. The ajax is written in javascripts/collaborations.js:
    $(document).ready(function()
{
 // alert(1);

```
 $('#collaboration_user_name').on('keyup', function() { 

      // text = $(this).val();
      // alert(text);

       $.ajax({ url: "/collaborations", 
       beforeSend: function( xhr ) { 
        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" ); 
      } 
     }).done(function( data ) { 
      if( console && console.log ) { 
        console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) ); 
        //alert()

      } 
    });
 });
});
```

Here is the collaboration#search_collaboration action within the collaborations controller:

```
 def collaboration_search
  name_search = params[:collaboration][:user_name].to_s
  @users_by_name = User.where('name Like ?', "%#{params[:collaboration][:user_name]}%")
   render json: @users_by_name.map do |user|
     { name: user.name, id: user.id}
  end
```

end

And just for testing purposes I kept my collaborations/search_collaboration.js.erb very simple:

```
alert('hello');
```

however if someone can point me in the right direction for how to list the names of the users returned from the collaboration_search action that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to suggest that you're trying to index into something as a hash, when it is, in fact, nil:

```
undefined method `[]&#39; for nil:NilClass
```

The `[]` refers to hash indexing -- such as `params[:collaboration]`. My immediate guess would be that you're not serving the params to this controller action in the format expected, so that `params[:collaboration]` is `nil`, and you're trying to index into that `params[:collaboration][:user_name]`, provoking said error.

This jives with your current jQuery code, which doesn't send the data at all (where are you sending `text` as a parameter, either in the querystring or as a jQuery.ajax() param?), not to mention in that specific format.

You could either do something like this:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/collaborations?collaboration=#{text}",
   #..etc
```

Or you could use the `ajax` function's data method to give it a parameter as a hash instead of just throwing it in the URL. The docs for that function should give you more information.

> I'd strongly recommend the latter, as you expect nested hashes in your controller `[:collaboration][:user_name]`, which is not easily supported in a querystring parameter.

To see what the parameters are coming in as, I suggest throwing something like this in your Ruby controller:

```
puts "PARAMS: #{params.inspect}"
```

That should go above anything causing an error. It will print out the params in your server log (the terminal tab where you typed `rails server` or `rails s`), so that you can see what the parameters are, and whether this hypothesis is accurate, and how to fix the problem.

As a final note, I don't think you're actually hitting your `.js.erb` file at all. Your action just returns a response to the jQuery ajax function. That response is in your function called on `done()`, and the response data is, in your current code, referred to as `data`. I'd alert that `data` once you've gotten past this error, to see how your controller is serializing things. And then, without that `js.erb` file, you can simply update the DOM with the results from the jQuery.

(Final note, I can't think of an occasion where you'd need to test for `if console && console.log`, and I'm not sure that test won't throw an error. I might be wrong, though.)

Answer (score 0):

The UX Jargon for what you what you are trying to build is autocomplete dropdown or autocomplete combobox. It is actually a fairly complicated UI element that I wouldn't both programming from scratch. You should use a library like JQuery. JQuery is built into core Rails so I should just be a matter of including the right library. Here Is a sample of the element from JQuery.

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.7/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

You can look at the source code using the browser development tools

Here is JQuery Autocomplete docs

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

You can look at the code in you

Here is another implementation
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxcombobox/index.htm

Comment: This is not a answer. It is just links about `jQuery` lib.

Comment: The roll-your-own autocomplete route is a useful exercise for learning, but beware that it could be considerable work to make it accessible to all users (e.g. users who depend on screen-readers). If you choose a 3rd party widget as suggested or another such as [Typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/), which used to ship with Twitter Bootstrap, hopefully accessibility details have been taken care of. Also at least be aware of HTML5's datalist element (sadly [not supported by all browsers](http://beta.caniuse.com/#search=datalist) at time of writing).